# bootstrap 3 open new link from tab click

Tags: css, url, hyperlink, tabs

i would like to know how to open a url link from a tab click. in the example below few tab pages. on click of the icon-clock i want to open a book table url link.
i have tried adding the link as shown but it does not work.
thanks

```
        <div id="tabs" class="tabs">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#section-1"><span><i class="icon-menu"></i></span></a>
                    </li>                       
                    <li><a href="#section-2"><span><i class="icon-comment-4"></i></span></a>
                    </li>   
                    <li><a href="#section-3"><span><i class="icon-home-6"></i></span></a>
                    </li>           
                    <li><a href="book/table"><span><i class="icon-clock"></i></span></a>
                    </li>                               
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends on where you are doing this and what you are using to run this html file.
If you are using this on a simple server without node, use this `href="./book/table.html"` if it is an html file. The `./` will tell the browser that you are want to start from the current directory(where your **index.html** file is) and then go to book directory and open table.html.

If it is an external link, you should do `https://something.com/book/table`

If you're using node to serve this file, you may try `href="/book/table"`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried various methods and these do not work. i can see the proper link displayed when i hover the mouse but when i click i get a blank tab page appear.